# java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database

Tags: database, netbeans

First, this is my first time with Apache Derby. I am using netbeans, willing to use embedded apache derby but it showing following exception

```
enter code here


    String url="jdbc:derby:C:/Users/ankit/.netbeans-derby/kushal11";


    try
    {

    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"APP","APP"); 
} catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

    try {
          PreparedStatement pstmt1 = 
                con.prepareStatement("select COUNT(*) as c from cus_details where cust_name='"+s1+"'");
        ResultSet executeQuery = pstmt1.executeQuery();
      int a=0;

     while (executeQuery.next()){
         a=executeQuery.getInt("c");
      System.out.print(a);
     }
```

But, when I am trying to insert data into the database, it is giving me the following error

```
enter code here
```

java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:/Users/ankit/.netbeans-derby/kushal11' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@9fef6f, see the next exception for details.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to declare

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

I don't know if you did declare it, but in your code you just have con without declaring it with Connection